# Visual Studio fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'pthreadVC2.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pthreads

I have just installed Visual Studio 2013 on my Windows 8 computer, and I tried to follow this tutorial: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj620919%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

However, when I tried to build the code, I got this error:
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'pthreadVC2.lib'

I have no idea what that file is, and why is it missing. How do I resolve this?
p.s. I've seen similar questions here on SO, but I don't quite understand the solutions. I tried to look in the project properties, but I don't know what should I look for. Everything seems to be default (I just installed the VS).

Comment: The code you're compiling needs the [Win32 port of pthreads](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest). The pthreads .lib needs to be put somewhere that the linker knows about. There are instructions floating around the Internet suggesting to dump the .lib and .dll into Program Files or somewhere equally awful.

Comment: why does a simple "hello world" program need it?

Comment: I did as you said, and the error went away, but I'm still confused why would brand new installation of VS need pthreads code to compile 'hello world' program.

Comment: As I said before: it doesn't.

Comment: Then why did it throw the error?

Comment: Because of some factor that you haven't disclosed, such as having pthreads somehow foul up your include/lib paths, copy/pasting in third-party code that tries to use pthreads, or some other circumstance.